# HashIds with MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, hashids

Is there any implementention of HashIds with Maria DB similar to the PostgreSQL implementation that would allow to manage encode and decode directly from the database ?  I couldn't find any mention on the official website.

Thanks for any feedback or idea.
Adam.

Comment: May we please have a usage example? (This might help to add clarity to the question.)

Comment: Sure. Hashids with PostgreSQL defines hash_encode and hash_decode functions that can be used directly in SQL query to encode and decode obfuscated ids. So the idea was to have something similar with MariaDB.
SELECT hash_encode(123, 'this is my salt', 10); -- Result: 4xpAYDx0mQ
SELECT hash_decode('4xpAYDx0mQ', 'this is my salt', 10); -- Result: 123

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that by `Hashid` you mean a function that converts long integers into a HASH, which is mainly used to make primary keys inaccessible to the user (For example YT movie ids).

MariaDB doesn't have a native function for, but it is possible to extend MariaDB with a [user defined function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/creating-user-defined-functions/) written in C, which for example uses the [hashid library](https://github.com/tzvetkoff/hashids.c).

Another alternative would be to hash/unhash the integer inside your client application. Depending on the programming language there are a lot of libraries available.

Also Postgres doesn't have a native hashid function, it's a 3rd party extension/user defined function.

Comment: Ok. I think that would do and will definitely have a look. What about for MySQL? Do you know if there is any similar extension as I couldn't find any implementation so far for HashId at the MySQL database level.

Comment: Like MariaDB MySQL doesn't offer a hashid function. But if you create an UDF function it can be used both in MySQL and MariaDB since the UDF API is the same.

Comment: you can also write a [UDF](https://github.com/pluots/sql-udf) in Rust if you like.